# Does anyone know how I can get the "real" size of the UIImageView instead of creating a frame

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview

I was hoping there was some sort of function that could take the real size of my picture

```
CGRect myImageRect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0, 210.0f);  // 234
            UIImageView *myImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myImageRect];

            [myImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"start.png"]];
```

And with CGRectMake which does something like this ..( imageViewHeight ,

CGFloat imageViewHeight = [myImage frame].size.height;

So that I could get the real size instead of having to define it like you can seen above.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really get what you're asking, but here's a shot:

If you have a UIImage, and you want to know its size, you can ask it for its `-[UIImage size]` property.

However, if you want to create a UIImageView that's the same size as a UIImage, then you can just use `-[UIImageView initWithImage:]`, which will automatically set the frame of the UIImageView to correspond to the dimensions of the image.

If, however, you're just looking to change the dimensions of a currently existing view, there's really no easy way to do that without messing around with the view's `frame`.  You could maybe apply an affine transform to scale it, but it's easier to manipulate the frame.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're asking to add the image to the imageview without first creating a frame. If this is the case, you can do the following:

```
UIImageView *myImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"start.png"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, you are looking for the size of the image used in UIImageView object. To do that, there is not a function built in **UIImageView** but you can do it this way:

```
NSString* image= [myImage image].accessibilityIdentifier; // Get the image's name
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:image]; // Create an image object with that name
CGSize size = img.size; // Get the size of image
```

Hope this helps your question.